# respond_with having issue with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1, responders, rails-roar

I am upgrading my Rails app from `4.1.1` to `5.1.4`.

I am using `roar-rails` gem to parsing and rendering REST documents. I am facing some issues as `responders` gem has been extracted to separate gem.

`respond_with` has been moved to 'responders' gem.

My `rails 4` code lookgs like this:

PostsController:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    posts = current_user.posts
    respond_with posts, :represent_with => PostsRepresenter, current_user: current_user
  end
end
```

## My representers for Post

```
module PostsRepresenter
  # Rails 4 code
  # include Roar::Representer::JSON::HAL
  # Rails 5 code (after adding responders) --------
  include Roar::JSON
  include Roar::Hypermedia
  # Rails 5 code --------

  collection(
    :post,
    class: Post,
    extend: PostRepresenter,
    embedded: true)

    link :make do |args|
      p "............. #{args.inspect}"
      # In rails 4, args are coming correctly what is passing from Controller
      # But in rails 5, args is coming `nil`
      posts_path if args[:current_user].can_create?(Post)
    end
end
```

## Post representer

```
module PostRepresenter
  # Rails 4 code
  # include Roar::Representer::JSON::HAL
  # Rails 5 code (after adding responders) --------
  include Roar::JSON
  include Roar::Hypermedia
  # Rails 5 code --------

  property :title
  property :description
  property :author

  link :self do |args|
    post_path(id) if args[:current_user].can_read?(self)
  end

  link :remove do |args|
    post_path(id) if args[:current_user].can_delete?(self)
  end

  link :edit do |args|
    post_path(id) if args[:current_user].can_update?(self)
  end
end
```

> I am facing issue with `args` which are passing through `Controller`,
>   after `rails 5`, its coming **`nil`**.

I have debug the issue and found that in `responders` gem, options are coming in `respond_with` method, but I think it could not send it to `roar-rails`.

`/path-to-gem/vendor/responders-master/lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb`
Here is snippet:

```
def respond_with(*resources, &block)
  if self.class.mimes_for_respond_to.empty?
    raise "In order to use respond_with, first you need to declare the " \
      "formats your controller responds to in the class level."
  end

  mimes = collect_mimes_from_class_level
  collector = ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector.new(mimes, request.variant)
  block.call(collector) if block_given?

  if format = collector.negotiate_format(request)
    _process_format(format)
    options = resources.size == 1 ? {} : resources.extract_options!
    options = options.clone
    options[:default_response] = collector.response
    p "====================== options :: #{options.inspect}"
    # Options are correct till here but coming `nil` on representers 
    (options.delete(:responder) || self.class.responder).call(self, resources, options)
  else
    raise ActionController::UnknownFormat
  end
end
```

> Please let me know what needs to be done here that make `args`
>   available in `representers`

Answer (score 1):

`respond_with` was deprecated from rails `4.2.1`.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

Comment: So what replaced it?

Comment: @MingweiSamuel they were migrated to a external gem https://github.com/heartcombo/responders